# Предзагрузка изображений средствами JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Для игры нужно подгрузить заранее в районе 12 изображений, причем эти изображения могут варьироваться от случая к случаю. То есть сейчас мне нужно подгрузить одни 12 изображений (SVG), а завтра нужно будет другие 12. Поэтому вариант помещения их в `<div style="display: none;"><img...></div>` не подходит, ибо в этом случае придется постоянно грузить все изображения, а понадобятся мне из них всего 12. Поэтому было решено подгружать их средствами JavaScript перед началом игры. Для этого я реализовал небольшой класс "AssetsPreloader", который, пока что, имеет единственный метод "preload", который принимает массив из объектов вида `{src: "ссылка", id: "id"}` и подгружает необходимые изображения путем простого создания экземпляра класса `Image()` (нативный).

```
class AssetsPreloader {
  static preload(arr) {
    arr.map((a) => {
      let img = new Image(); img.src = a.src; img.id = a.id;

      (this.assets = this.assets || []).push(img);
    });
  }
}
```

Все подгруженные изображения в итоге попадают в статическое свойство `assets` этого класса.

Следующим в коде идет отрисовка первого кадра игры, где эти изображения уже используются. И, в общем-то, проблема в том, что отрисовка не происходит. До нее выполнение кода доходит, это я проверял, и после нее код выполняется, но сами изображения не отрисовываются. Насколько я понимаю, происходит это потому, что изображения не успевают загрузиться (даже несмотря на то, что загрузка их происходит с диска). Однако, если запросить отрисовку первого кадра прямо из консоли браузера, то все работает как надо и кадр рисуется нормально.

Весь код в общем и целом выглядит примерно так:

```
class AssetsPreloader {
  static preload(arr) {
    arr.map((a) => {
      let img = new Image(); img.src = a.src; img.id = a.id;

      (this.assets = this.assets || []).push(img);
      this.done = true;
    });
  }
}

AssetsPreloader.preload([
  {src: "images/image.svg", id: "id_of_image"},
  ...
]);

// ...
GAME.field.draw();
```

В итоге, вопрос сводится к тому, как максимально правильно подгружать изображения (да и вообще различного рода файлы) так, чтобы, пока они не загрузились, код далше не выполнялся. Причем, возможно, на экране в этот момент будет какой-нибудь прогресс-бар (то есть полностью фризиться скрипт тоже не должен). Первым делом мне в голову пришло добавить весь остальной код в коллбэк к методу `preload()`, но эта идея успехом не увенчалась.

Прошу помощи. Интересует не только как, но и как наиболее правильно (best-practice, все такое).

P.S. Файл скрипта подключен к странице с атрибутом `defer`. При использовании, например, `async`, отрисовка либо происходит, либо нет (отчего зависит - не могу сказать). А вешать в сам код обработчики проверки загрузки страницы, готовности DOM или что-то в этом роде не хочу.

Comment: Попробуйте использовать событие onload для каждого изображения, дождавшись загрузки каждого, а затем можно произвести дальнейшие действия

Answer (score 1):

Привожу кусок своего кода предзагрузки изображений. Принимает в качестве аргумента функцию handler которая выполнится когда все изображения загрузятся (или сообщат о сбое при попытки загрузки изображения). Специально привожу в неизменённом состоянии, точно работающем правильно. .preloader меняется с использованием jquery, если он не нужен, можно убрать. Остальное нативный javascript.

```
Slider3D.prototype.loadAllImages = function( handler ) {
    var self = this;
    var currentImageLoadedIndex = 0;

    for ( var index = 0; index < self.settings.images.length; index++ ) {
        self.data.images[index] = new Image();
        self.data.images[index].onload = self.data.images[index].onerror = function(){
            if ( ++currentImageLoadedIndex >= self.settings.images.length ) {
                self.settings.element.find('.preloading').hide();
                if ( typeof handler === 'function' ) handler();
            } else {
                self.settings.element.find('.preloading').css('width',((currentImageLoadedIndex/self.settings.images.length)*100) + '%');
            }
        };
        self.data.images[index].src = self.settings.images[index];
    }
};
```

Comment: Поясню, что разница с callback к вашему preload и callback к моему loadAllImages в том, что вы пытались запустить callback сразу после того, как создали объекты изображений, как результат - картинки ещё не скачаны. В моём коде запуск callback (handler()) произойдёт только после того, как все изображения будут загружены, что проверяется по количеству посланных на предзагрузку изображений и номеру соответствующему итерации очередного загруженного сообщения.

Comment: Ну, в общем, ситуация такова: ваша мысль о том, что коллбэк стоит выполнять только по onload мне действительно помогла, но реализация, естественно, у меня другая. Поэтому к ответу ставлю +1, но советую вам так и написать в ответе (отредактировать), что нужно просто выполнять коллбэк по onload'у картинки. Тогда ответ и решением можно будет отметить :)